# JSON to Java Objects using gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I am using Retrofit/Okhttp with gson. I want to display all events. Usually an event should contrain province, organizer and addr. I dont know how to map it in the right way to a object like "Event". The JSON starts with "events" and contains numbers like "565419" and "13694" can I ignore them?

**My JSON:**

```
{
   "events": {
      "565419": {
         "13694": {
            "category": {
               "id": "6",
               "name": "Sam",
               "icon": "http://.gif",
               "params": [
                  {
                     "q": "c",
                     "cid": "6",
                     "p": "1"
                  },
                  {
                     "q": "pc",
                     "cid": "6",
                     "pid": "15",
                     "p": "1"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "province": {
               "id": "15",
               "name": "Name of province“,
               "params": [
                  {
                     "q": "p",
                     "pid": "15",
                     "p": "1"
                  },
                  {
                     "q": "cp",
                     "cid": "6",
                     "pid": "15",
                     "p": "1"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "event": {
               "date": "01.09.",
               "time": "1535752800",
               "dayofweek": "Sunday“,
               "id": "13694",
               "title": "My Title“,
               "text": "My Text“,
               "fulltext": "MyFullText“,
               "lng": "0",
               "lat": "0",
               "tstart": "90000",
               "tend": "150000",
               "opt": "0",
               "holiday": "1",
               "params": {
                  "q": "e",
                  "eid": "13694"
               }
            },
            "organizer": {
               "company": "MyCompany“,
               "firstname": "MyFirstname“,
               "lastname": "MyLastname“,
               "street": "MyStreet“,
               "plz": "12334“,
               "city": "MyCity“,
               "phone": „123345323“,
               "id": "7580",
               "params": [
                  {
                     "q": "s",
                     "vid": "7580"
                  },
                  {
                     "q": "v",
                     "id": "7580"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "addr": {
               "id": "1432",
               "plz": "01234“,
               "name": "MyName“,
               "street": "MyStreet“,
               "location": "MyLocation“,
               "lat": "5657657676“,
               "lng": "12356578999“,
               "params": {
                  "q": "a",
                  "aid": "1432",
                  "p": "1"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
```

Thank you for your help.